# Tkinter binding to inside a function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Currently this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def a(self, event = None):

        print ("a")

    def create_widgets(self):

        def b(event = None):

            print(entry.get())

        entry = Entry()
        entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Button(text = "b", command = b).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
        master.bind("<Return>", b)

root = Tk()
app = Application(master = root)
app.mainloop()
```

So far it calls a, but replacing self.a with self.b to make it call b instead brings up AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'b' and with just b returns a NameError: 'b' is not defined.

So how can I make the bind call b like the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I make the bind call b like the button?

In my opinion, the best solution is to make `b` a proper method of the class and not a nested function. Make your widgets proper attributes as well and the code becomes much easier to write:

```
class Application(Frame):
    def a(self, event = None):
        print ("a")

    def b(self, event = None):
        print(self.entry.get())

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.entry = Entry()
        self.entry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Button(text = "b", command = b).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        ...
        master.bind("<Return>", self.b)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! This worked perfectly. I didn't actually know you could do that, still learning tkinter.